# Im trying to make a new folder but i ran into a problem

Tags: python, operating-system

when i'm trying to use `os.chdir` then it also changes somehow of the paths in other things
heres more context:

The folder creator

```
def create_world():
    global path
    path = 'saved_data'
    os.chdir(path)
    os.makedirs('world2')
```

a file reader

```
def read_txt_file(destination, line1):
    file = open('text/' + str(destination) + '.txt', 'r')
    f = file.readlines()
    txt = []
    for line in f:
        txt.append(line.strip())
    return txt[line1 - 1]
```

when i try to create a new folder the `os.chdir` changes the path of the other files but python just says that that file dosen't exist

I Found out that when i make a new folder it saves the directory like this:
before: C:\Users\prcha\PycharmProjects-- The Adventure --
after: C:\Users\prcha\PycharmProjects-- The Adventure --\saved_data

Comment: What value is stored in ```str(destination)``` if you print it out?

Comment: Captain Caveman it will say the destination like in the folder buttons so it will print out 'buttons' i fyou put the entire thing you get 'text/buttons/button1.txt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found out that i can use a small line of code to fix the paths instantly to the other paths like this:

```
FULLPATHold = os.getcwd()
```

FULLPATH = ''
character1 = '\ '
for char in character1:
character1 = char
break
for char in FULLPATHold:
if char == str(character1):
FULLPATH = FULLPATH + '/'
else:
FULLPATH = FULLPATH + char
FULLPATH = FULLPATH + '/'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `path = os.path.join('saved_data', 'world2')` to create your `path` before trying to make the directory.

Also, if 'saved_data' is the entire path that you're using, it probably won't work, unless that path happens to be in the same folder as the script. You'd need to do something like `r'C:\saved_data'` or `~/saved_data`, depending on your OS.

Personally, I use the `pathlib` library to handle things like this. For example:

```
directoryBase = "{}/{}/Bucket {}/RB".format(part1, time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"), part2)
pathlib.Path(directoryBase).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

This will check whether directoryBase already exists, and if not, create the destination folder and any `Parent` folders that also do not yet exist.

Comment: yes the folder is in the script but the first solution didnt work, same thing happend and the second thing is too complicated to look at but thanks